# Puede cc compilar un archivo .cpp?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Soy nuevo usando un entorno Linux para compilar y correr mis programas en c y c++.
Como tal me he dado cuenta que para compilar archivos.c en terminal ocupo de **cc** o **gcc**, caso contrario con archivos.cpp que ocupan **g++**

Mi duda era que si existia alguna manera de compilar un **archivo.cpp** usando **cc** dentro de la consola?

Answer (score 0):

En este caso lo importante no es la extensión sino el contenido del fichero.

Un compilador de C solo será capaz de compilar código fuente compatible con C, mientras que para compilar código C++ necesitarás un compilador propio de C++.

Las extensiones no son limitantes y, por ejemplo, nada te impide crear un archivo `prueba.c` que contenga un programa completo escrito en ADA... no es una buena práctica pero se puede hacer.

El caso es que tienes que fijarte en el contenido que quieres procesar. Si este contenido es C++ tendrás que usar un compilador de C++, mientras que el si el código fuente es C podrás perfectamente usar un compilador de C.